# How to make an audio stream in C#? (general)

Tags: c#, audio, waveform

I have been doing a synthesizer project on Atmel microcontrollers using C++, but I had a lack of knowledge on timing, because `ctime` library is using integer millisecond parameters (if it would even work on Atmel), but I have a need to output (for example) a square wave with frequencies up to 44100Hz, which, obviously, changes output state from `-1` to `1` with periods that are 88.2 times shorter than a millisecond.

Now I am learning to build PC audio applications using C#. So, there are my questions:

1. How would you time app to do something exactly 1/88.2 ms in C#, using, for example, time comparing function and only native libraries (if that is actually possible)?
2. How could you output your steam (for example `1` and `-1` values with any loudness) to your PC's sound device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally PC audio devices require you to send [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) packets in specific buffer sizes (for example 200ms).

For a sample rate of 44100, you put 11025 Samples (per channel) in a buffer and send it to the audio device via an API such as [DirectSound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for which managed libraries exist. Alternatively you can use the [Windows Core Audi API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) directly. There are many others.

**No need to control each sample individually**.

A Sample can be anything from a list of 8/16/24/32/64 bits and is stored in a specific data type, such as:

- `unsigned byte` for **8 bit samples**
- `short` or `Int16` for **16 bits  samples**
- C# does **not** support **24 bit integers** natively
- `Int32` or `float` for **32 bit samples**
- etc.

Essentlially you have to tell your audio device how many samples (`SampleRate`) of what type (`SampleSize`) on how many channels (`ChannelNum`) you'll send it, agree on a buffer size and go!

Comment: Thanks! Another piece of info I will actually use!

Answer (score 0):

The basic steps:

Prepare an (in memory) "sound file" for example two channels (16 Bit each) and a sampling rate of 44.1 kHz (the CD rate).

Send these bytes to a DC Converter, usually called an "audio device"

You might use a library like `NAudio` to do this.